# I want to add the language code to path so it could be /language_code

Tags: python, django

I am developing a multi-language website and I managed through internationalization to make the locale files and translating the web pages but my problem is that I want to add the language code to the path.

```html
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post" id="languageForm">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                            <select name="language" id="selectLanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"
                                                    style="height: 500px;">
                                                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                                                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                                {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                                {% for language in languages %}
                                                    <option value="{{ language.code }}"
                                                            {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                                                    </option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Go">-->
                                        </form>
```

I am using this select to choose the languages available and my path pattern is as follow:

```
`path('home', views.home, name='home'),` so some home I want it to be 'home/en' for example so how can I do so?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regex path matcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path)

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^home/(?P<language>\w{2})$',views.home,name='home')
]
```

And in your `views.home` function you should take an extra keyword argument named `language` for your two-character language code.

The reason why you have to use regex is that django's new (the one introduced in 2.0) `path` function doesn't let you have a slash when it is parsing the URL. If you want to use something like `home_en` then you don't have to use `re_path`.